# Droid4X With Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

Can Anybody guide me how can I use Droid4X Emulator In Android Studio.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I cant't find any option so please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Droid4X Setting Modifier v1.4.1](http://www.droid4x.com/bbs/viewthread.php?tid=743419&extra=page%3D1), a simple tool which you can use to modify the screen resolution, DPI, RAM, etc. To change the settings, please input the number (like 1, 2 or 3) as you see on your screen. 
Note: **TURN OFF** the emulator before running the program.
[Droid4X setting modifier running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8PwV.jpg)